# Techniques for fingerprinting a web based content management system (CMS)

Tags: cms, fingerprinting, enumeration

Let's say we have a random basic blog or informational website: just some pages with information, a sidebar with an overview of the archives, the normal stuff. We know of this website that it's built with a CMS. How can we get to know *which* CMS built this website?

So I'm looking for basic, general typicals of several much-used CMSs, so that we can get to know the working power behind any informational website or blog.

For example, a typical might be that WordPress adds such a line to the HTML:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.5.1" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic here. The guys on Reverse Engineering (in private beta now) told me it's on topic here.

Comment: The security implications would be for identifying what platform is in place to help focus attacks. Defensively, you would want to try to confuse such techniques to hide what is going on under the surface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are interested in finger printing a CMS. This can be done similar to what is done with nmap. You would need to compromise a library of unique urls, etc and than scan a page to see if they exhibit these.

You can use [BuiltWith.com](http://builtwith.com).

Here are some examples of it is use:

- [Joomla.org](http://builtwith.com/joomla.org) being positively identified as Joomla
- [Wordpress.org](http://builtwith.com/wordpress.org) being positively identified as Wordpress

Some other useful/related finds:

- [Nmap Plugin](http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2011/q2/490) to identify Drupal websites
- [Scritch](http://guess.scritch.org/?referer=direct&url=joomla.org) seems to have a script similar to BuiltWith
- [Wapalyzer Plugin](http://wappalyzer.com/download) to do some detections
- [web-sorrow](http://code.google.com/p/web-sorrow/): a perl based scanner which includes checks for CMS
- [Blind Elephant](http://blindelephant.sourceforge.net/): another scanner
- [plecost](https://code.google.com/p/plecost/): A wordpress specific scanner
- [whatweb](http://www.morningstarsecurity.com/research/whatweb): yet another scanner which doesn't seem to be as actively developed
- [OWASP Favicon DB](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_favicon_database): Not quite functional on its own, but if you hash the favicons as you download and they match, could be used as one indicator.

You could also do some google hacking with the url + keywords like "Joomla" or "Wordpress" to see if the site is listed in a showcase, they asked for help on a forum for a particular CMS and listed their site, comments, code hints, search for specific strings in the url, e.g., `inurl:index.php?option=com_content`.

Comment: Found this pretty good article with some background and thoughts at the theory level: http://anantshri.info/articles/web_app_finger_printing.html

Comment: wpscan is also useful for wordpress sites.

Comment: This is useful and fun, but doesn't really answer the question: I'm looking for the techniques used by these tools, not for the tools themselves. The link you provided in the comment is a better answer :-)

Comment: There are some other pieces of advice among the links, you can also look at their source code. Do you want to make your own product, or perform a fingerprinting?

Comment: I didn't see that some where open source. Now it's a very nice answer, thanks!

Comment: This may also come in handy: https://nerdydata.com/search - if you find something which looks like it should be a fingerprint, you can then search on other sites to see if they have the same line of code, but expose more details that your target site possibly removed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for Chrome, and probably Firefox too, that can identify the known infrastructure used in a visited site. Likely there are several plugins that do this type of analysis. In most cases, it is pretty easy to look at the source of a site and determine what CMS it is using, if any.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/builtwith-technology-prof/dapjbgnjinbpoindlpdmhochffioedbn?hl=en

Comment: Can you identify the plugin you describe? You say it's easy to determine which CMS by looking at the source, could you update your answer with a few examples of this?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/builtwith-technology-prof/dapjbgnjinbpoindlpdmhochffioedbn?hl=en  and for example WordPress would show a lot of wp-content and such common subdirectories in use

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the very good list given by Eric, I personnaly use [Wappalyzer](https://wappalyzer.com/) (a browser extension) which usually gives me the best results to fingerprint CMS during penetration tests.

Also, as far as I remember, Blind Elephant suffers from lack of updates and issues running on Kali (although it's part of the standard distro).